# Entity Framework select item where id is in other table

Tags: entity-framework

Tables:

- User (iduser)
- File (idfile, fk_iduser)
- Categ (idcat, name)
- File_deco (fk_idfile, fk_idcat)
- Fav (fk_iDfile, fk_iduser)

I'm looking for the equivalent EF expression for this SQL query:

```
Select * 
from File 
where fk_iduser = 1 
  and idfile in (Select fk_idfile 
                 from File_Deco 
                 where fk_idFile in (Select fk_iDfile from Fav))
```

Comment: Show us the code you've tried

Answer (score 1):

Use code below:

```
file=db.file.Where(u => u.fk_iduser == idCurrentUser);
var res=file.Where(f => f.Categ != null && f.Categ.File.FirstOrDefault(ff=>ff.FAV.FirstOrDefault(aa=>aa.fk_iduser==idCurrentUser && aa.fk_idFile==f.idFile)!=null)!=null);
```

Comment: While this code fragment may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful for future visitors if you explain why it solves the problem. Also, `Any` instead of `FirstOrDefault ... != null` would be an improvement.